# Prove that $\int \mathbf A \, dV = 0$, if . . .

Tags: integration, vector-analysis

...if inside the value $(\nabla , \mathbf A ) = 0$, and on the surface of the value $ A_{n} = 0$.

So, I need to prove that

$$
\int \mathbf A \, dV = 0. \tag{.0}
$$

I tried to prove it by the next way. $(\nabla , \mathbf A ) = 0$ means that the lines of the $ \mathbf A$-field are closed, and $ A_{n} = 0$ on the surface means that all the lines are inside the value and on the surface. So it means that the integral can be transformed into a number of integrals looks as

$$
\oint I \, d \mathbf l, \tag{.1}
$$

where I is the analogue of closed current. So all of these integral's are equal to 0.

But I have some doubts about correctness of the transition from $\int \mathbf A \, dV$ to (.1) and I need to prove (.0) more strictly. Can you help me?

Comment: $A$ is a vector field? What is $(\nabla, A)$? The divergence of $A$? What is $A_n$?

Comment: 1. Of course.
2. Yes, the divergence.
3. $A_{n}$ is a component perpendicular to the surface at the same point of surface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the vector field $x\mathbf{A}$.

By the divergence theorem we have that

$$0 = \int_{\partial \Omega} x\mathbf{A}\cdot n = \int_{\Omega} \operatorname{div} (x\mathbf{A}) = \int_{\Omega} (A_x + x\operatorname{div} \mathbf{A}) = \int_{\Omega} A_x,$$

and similarly for the other components of $A$.